# Examples of uses of different voltages as seen on motor nameplate

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, industrial-engineering

The electric motor nameplate (pictured) has a variety of different voltage configurations which are listed. I understand that the motor can be configured to run on different voltages by changing the way the windings are connected. The different voltage configurations are as follows:

- 690 VY - Wye (windings see 400V)
- 400 VD - Delta (windings see 400V)
- 660 VY - Wye (windings see 380V)
- 380 VD - Delta (windings see 380V)
- 415 VD - Delta (windings see 415V)
- 460 VD - Delta (windings see 460V)

For all of these configurations, the windings see between 380 - 460 V, or 1.33 - 2.33 A. So it makes sense that it can be configured in this way. However, the buildings and facilities that I am familiar with -working in- usually have 3 phase available at 240/415, or 230/400.

**So my question is**: in what parts of the world (or in what industries) have some of these alternative voltages? e.g. where do they use 3-phase at 380/660, or 400/690? Also where does 460 V come from?

[image: Motor name plate]

Comment: Have you considered how you measure the voltage? max value or rms?

Comment: @SolarMike I haven't considered that. How do you think that affects things?